# MySql many to many relationship query and filter

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables

```
        ***contacts                             contacts_tags                tags***
**cont_id  |  FirstName  |  LastName             cont_id  |  tag_id       tag_id  |  tag**    
      1    |    John     |    Doe                   1     |    13           13    |  Insurance
      2    |    Dan      |   Laundrin               2     |    16           14    |  Mortgage
      3    |   Chris     |   Sepin                  3     |    15           15    |  Friend
                                                    3     |    15           16    |  Realtor
```

When I output this query, I need to output all of the contact's info (FirstName, LastName and other fields such as phone, email etc...) but I have to filter this output's table by it's tag.

I can't figure out how to query and get all of the contacts info, and each of their tags, so I can sort by the tag's name.

Please assist!

Comment: Markup went to hell. Great

Comment: Have you got any SQL you tried to make this work?